# What happens to Dr. Chilton?

Tags: character, the-silence-of-the-lambs

In [*The Silence of the Lambs* (1991)](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0102926/), Dr. Lecter calls the newly appointed agent Starling and informs her that he is

> having an old friend for dinner

before hanging up the phone and starts following Dr. Chilton into the crowd.

There is no mentioning of what happens to Dr. Chilton in [*Hannibal* (2001)](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0212985/), the movie, does it say anywhere else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the novel, [*Hannibal* (1999)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hannibal_(Harris_novel)), [Chilton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frederick_Chilton) disappeared while on vacation in Jamaica seven years earlier; it is strongly suggested that Lecter murdered him.

He exists in the TV show [*Hannibal* (2013-15)](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt2243973/), but the events of said show take place before the movies, up through Red Dragon, and deviate from the original book/movie timeline.

Comment: yeah, TV show is very different; Freddy Lounds is a woman instead